# Django Heroku Postgres - ProgrammingError: relation does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm using Django 1.7, PostgresApp (PostgreSQL 9.4), Python 2.7.

I have followed this tutorial for setting up and creating the app: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial02/

In the Python shell, I kept getting errors like *"ProgrammingError: relation "app_table" does not exist*" for my database schema.

So I used the classes from the tutorial:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

and then in the shell I got (the correct values):

```
>>> Question.objects.all()
[]
>>> Choice.objects.all()
[]
```

Then, modifying the name *Choice* to *MyChoice* gives this:

```
>>> Question.objects.all()
[]
>>> MyChoice.objects.all()
...
ProgrammingError: relation "app_mychoice" does not exist.
```

Why is this happening?
I tried the answers suggested in other posts

```
./manage.py makemigrations; 
./manage.py migrate auth; 
./manage.py migrate and 
python manage.py syncdb
```

but nothing worked.

Comment: A bit confused, did you change `Choice(models.Model)` to `MyChoice(models.Model)`?

Comment: You shouldn't have to use `syncdb` for Django 1.7+. Why are you trying to change the model name from `Choice` to `MyChoice`? Did running `./manage.py makemigrations` create a migration to rename the table? What are the contents of your app's migrations folder, and which ones have you run? You could try dropping and recreating the database, then deleting the migrations and running  makemigrations again.

Comment: @Hybrid yes, that was the only change.

Comment: @Alasdair I changed it to see if it still works. `makemigrations` created a migration with the names updated. 
I dropped and recreated the database and I get the same error.

Comment: Alright so this looks like it is a migration issue, I always have problems with them as well, and end up having to `fake` and use flags like `initial`, but I don't want to give you a trial and error answer, hopefully someone who sees this has more experience with migrations and will be able to help

Comment: removing __port__ and __host__ from `settings.py` and then dropping and recreating the database fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I  had the same issue migrating an existing app to 1.11 and making some small changes to the model. The only solution I  found was ....

1. Clear all all files from the app's migrations dir leaving only the **init**.py file
2. Make sure that the admin.py file is empty
3. Run `manage.py makemigrations`
4. Run `manage.py sqlmigrate <app_label> 0001`
5. copy the sql output
6. using pgAdminIII select "Execute arbitrary SQL queries"
7. Paste and execute the SQL statements in pgAdminIII

This was the only solution I could find, bit of a hack true, but worked. Hope it helps.This would also work via psql terminal I suppose, but I used pgAdmin